# What USB descriptor fields are required for DirectShow to recognize a UVC camera?

Tags: usb, directshow, uvc

I am debugging UVC firmware on a custom USB web camera.  The camera enumerates and I am able to stream video on Ubuntu using guvcview.  However in Windows 10, the device enumerates and is shown as a Camera in device manager, but is not recognized by DirectShow (i.e it does not show up in the list of CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory devices).  The camera therefore is not able to be used by any application that uses the DirectShow interface such as openCV or VLC.  What descriptors are required to be implemented in the camera firmware so that DirectShow will recognize my UVC camera using the windows UVC driver?  The firmware implements UVC version 1.0.